# using injector with lazy loaded modules does not have access to material dialog

Tags: angular

I am trying to understand what is going on...  I have a somewhat complicated lazy-loading module structure, and I apologize in advance for this potentially being difficult to parse/follow but a basic simplification of the structure looks something like this:

page module (lazy loaded via route):

```
  declarations: [ MyHeaderComponent ],
  imports: [
     SomeModalModule,
     ...
```

MyHeaderComponent:

```
  constructor(
    private myService: MyService,
    ...
```

SomeModalModule:

```
  NgModule({
    imports: [
      ModalServiceModule,
      ...
```

ModalServiceModule:

```
  NgModule({
    imports: [
      MatDialogModule,
      ...
```

MyService:

```
  @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
  export class MyService {
    constructor(
      private modalService: ModalService,
      ...
```

ModalService:

```
  @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
  export class ModalService {
    constructor(
      private dialog: MatDialog,
      ...
```

The module for the main component for the route imports the module for the modal that the header component can display.  That module for the modal imports the modal service module, which imports material dialog...  The header component injects "MyService" in the constructor function, that is the service responsible for opening the modal.

When I try to visit this route, I am getting:

NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(FoldersModule)[MyService -> MyService -> MyService -> ModalService -> MatDialog -> MatDialog -> MatDialog]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialog!

If I change MyService's `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` to `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'any' })` then it works fine...  I am assuming this has to do with lazy loaded modules having different injectors, and from what I've read, `{ providedIn: 'any' }` has been deprecated...  How am I supposed to solve this problem if I can't use `any` ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer is to add:

```
providers: [ MyService ]
```

to the page module, and then it will work...